# DoCmd.RunSQL on update query - first run 0 update , updating only second run

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I do run pretty complex code in Access VBA. It pulls data from Excel or from other query into table in an Access frontend database. Then I want to run `DoCmd.RunSQL` that updates backend database based on this temporary data, but this line of code  acts weirdly.

1. When I run the code it updates 0 records.
2. If I `debug.print` the code into immediate window, and run it from there, it updates the records as expected.
3. When I take the SQL string into Access query builder, again it updates the records.
4. If I use `SetWarnings = True`, and it shows warning that I'm about to update 0 records, I press no, VBA throws error on the `DoCmd.RunSQL`. I press `Run` again, and on the same line, now it wants to update all the records as expected
5. I tried to run the query twice within the code. In both tests it almost seemed to be a solution, but now again it is updating 0 records.

I tried to use loop that runs for set time (something like Excel's `Application.wait`), suspecting that maybe temporary data in table have to refresh for database to see it, or something.

Anyone knows where is the problem? Do I have to refresh tables somehow or something? Thank you in advance.

```sql
UPDATE (SELECT [AUC],[Comment] FROM [AuC] IN 'C:\Users\test.accdb') AS Q1, [tempComments] 
SET [Q1].[Comment] = [tempComments].[Comment] 
WHERE [Q1].[AUC] = [tempComments].[AUC]
```

Comment: Try linking table from that external source into local database. Then run `UPDATE` query.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
With Access.DoCmd
    .RunSQL "[AuC] IN 'C:\Users\test.accdb' SET [AuC].[Comment] = [tempComments].[Comment] WHERE [AuC].[AUC] = [tempComments].[AUC]"
End With
```